# is foreach with lambda prone to commodification errors

Tags: java, concurrency

```
ArrayList<IFoo> objs = new ArrayList<>();

public void add(IFoo foo) {
    objs.add(foo);
}

public void loop() {
    objs.forEach(obj -> {
        obj.doSomething(message);
    });
}
```

is this method prone to ConcurrentModificationException errors or

should I make the copy of the array

Should I create an iterator?

or should I mark my both methods synchronized?

Comment: You shouldn't modify a collection you are iterating over.

Comment: no better or worse than normal 'for-each' iteration.

Comment: That is the shorthand way of doing `for(Object obj: objs)`, which in turn is the shorthand way of obtaining an Iterator and iterating over the collection. The collection that handles the collection is responsible for the Exceptions thrown. `ArrayList`'s iterator does throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` while the iterator is accessed after it has been modified. So if your code is doing that, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: synchronized will only help you if you lock the `objs` while iterating, and you know you won't modify it in the current loop.  Note: you could look at `CopyOnWriterArrayList` which allows modification while iterating.

Comment: There's a possibility that another thread will call `add` while some other thread is executing `method`, what to do then?

Comment: Synchronization has nothing to do with this issue. You can get a ConcurrentModificationException by just doing this: `objs.forEach(obj -> {objs.remove(0)});

Comment: @searchengine27 will collection throw the CME exception if another thread changed the collection via `add` method while iteration was in progress? if then how to safeguard it?

Comment: I updated my answer below, but the short answer is that you can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so I'm putting all this in the comments, but I think this is getting too lengthy to put there so here's an answer instead.

What you have is the shorthand way of doing

```
for(Object obj: objs){ ... }
```

which in turn is the shorthand way of obtaining an Iterator and iterating over the collection. The `Iterator` that handles the collection is responsible for the Exceptions thrown. ArrayList's iterator does throw a ConcurrentModificationException while the iterator is accessed after it has been modified. So if your code is doing that, then yes. Otherwise, no.

NOTE: `ConcurrentModificationException` although containing the word Concurrent does not necessarily have anything to do with multithreading. This is a very important distinction to make. You can get a `ConcurrentModificationException` to be thrown just by merely doing this:

```
objs.forEach(obj -> {objs.remove(0)});
```

It is true that multiple `Thread`s doing this can also cause this, but the exception really has nothing to do with multithreading. `ConcurrentModificationException` just means the `ArrayList` was modified concurrently while it was being accessed, where concurrent in this context means at the same time rather than the more traditional computing meaning of multithreading.

EDIT:

I saw a comment you made about protecting it, and also another about it being in a lib you don't have control over. The best way to truly protect it is probably to make a copy of the `List` in that case. The problem is that the lib is a black box, and you can't control whether they modify the collection and more aptly, whether or not they block/lock/control their insertions/removals from the collection. Probably creating a shallow copy of the List is enough. See [Collections#copy(List, List)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy(java.util.List,%20java.util.List)[Collections#copy(List,%20List))
or [ArrayList#ArrayList(Collection)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection))

Comment: thanks, your edit helps, question what if I mark both methods as `synchronized` will I achieve the safety from CME exception., I'm actually developing this lib that users would be using on a server side environment where it's multithreaded. LIB contains both methods and user of the lib is calling them

Comment: When I was talking about the use of the word concurrent, I was trying to call out that it has nothing to do with concurrency in the terms of computing. It just means it's being modified as it is being iterated upon. That is, using synchronized will not help you. If from within the same `Thread` you attempt to modify the collection while you're iterating then synchronization will not help you. If you're absolutely sure that you can't do that, then synchronization will protect against other `Thread`s who are not iterating (but while your thread is) from modifying the collection.

Comment: same thread is not modifying the collection as it's iterating, so in a way each operation is atomic, either same thread is adding to the list or iterating through the list, but i worry about `threadB` adding to the list while `threadA` is iterating the list.

Comment: Well even at that. You also mentioned in another comment how it's in a lib and you don't know how it will be used, but even if you did you shouldn't trust the lib to never change anyway, and you cant really lock around it because it's in the lib. For that, a shallow copy of the List and then iterating on the shallow copy is the safest way to protect it. Synchronization or blocking only helps you iff you protect on all and any modifications and iterations to the collection. Another thing to note is that synchronized blocks, while making a shallow copy wont block another Thread from doing work

Comment: ok, I understand copy is the way to go, what do you favor-> `Object[] temp = objs.toArray();` or `Collections.copy(temp, objs);`

Comment: I would stick with `Collections.copy` or passing your `objs` into the constructor for `ArrayList` which also makes a shallow copy.

Comment: quick question, will I also run into the same problem? i.e. CME throwing up even if I use Vector?

Comment: also another question, can it also happen with sorting in progress, like `messages.sort((msgA, msgB) -> {return 0;});`

Answer (score 1):

This will throw if you modify the `ArrayList` in `doSomething` or in another thread, as any form of iteration should.

But if you're not doing that, there's no reason to worry.

Comment: it's a lib so I don't know how will it be used, possibly used in highly concurrent system like on the web server.

Comment: array is not changing within the `method`, however, another thread might call `add` during the loop, so what to do in that case?

Comment: In that case you shouldn't be using a bare ArrayList anyway. Wrap it in Collections.synchronizedList, in which case forEach will do the right thing automatically, which is to say, only one thread will get to work on the list at a time. There is no list implementation that will do better than that, not really.  Making a copy of the list would work but you'd have to lock the list while you made the copy.

Comment: just to reiterate and confirm, here's the scenario, `threadA` has called the `loop` method and iteration is in progress, now in between `threadB` comes and calls the `add` method, shall I mark both methods `synchronized` to safeguard or create an array copy in the `loop`?, (note: `loop` method is not changing the array, it's the add method that does)

Comment: There isn't really a need to use a synchronized or threadsafe collection in all cases where multiple threads are using the collection. Imagine a scenario where all threads are reading from the collection 98 percent of the time and only writing 2 percent. In this case it is far more efficient to maintain an `ArrayList` and then use a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, for instance.

Comment: @user2727195, if you use `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())` you shouldn't need to do anything else to do any locking.  Marking the methods synchronized won't make any difference.

Comment: @searchengine27 in that scenario you might as well use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are modifying the list like adding or removing elements.However if you are changing the value/properties on an object iterated you should be good (as you are attempting).

Below example for ConcurrentModificationException with traditional loop and using Lambda, both are prone to failures.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Temp {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(1);

        for(Integer data :l){
            l.add(99);
        }

        l.forEach(obj -> {
            l.add(99);
        });
    }
}
```

For your case where you are worried about some other thread modifying the collection please create a copy of the list to iterate, use the Collections api to copy the array.